# Unable to map custom domain to API Gateway (from Godaddy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a custom domain (say, `myapi.com`) for my API Gateway but am running into problems. The domain is currently registered on GoDaddy. So far, I've followed [this](https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/custom-domain-in-aws-api-gateway-a2b7feaf9c74) tutorial and done the following:

1. Obtained a certificate for `myapi.com` and `*.myapi.com` from the AWS Certificate Manager.
2. Mapped the domain `myapi.com` (not `*.myapi.com` as I don't need it yet) to an API in the API Gateway.
3. Added a CNAME entry for the resulting "target domain name" in GoDaddy.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Now here's the problem: When I do `ping myapi.com` I get: `No address associated with hostname`. I'm not sure what's causing this, so would really appreciate some help. And while we're at it, are there any other steps I need to perform before this works as expected?

Comment: You need to clean your DNS cache first

Comment: @TuanVA I did that with `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` (on Ubuntu) and can see with `systemd-resolve --statistics` that the current cache size is zero. It was 68 before this. However, there's no change in the `ping` output. :(

Comment: If you ping abc.com, and no IP returned, then your DNS setting is an issue from DNS. use https://ping.eu/traceroute/ to confirm your DNS setting

Comment: I've tried a few traceroute tools and they all end up showing blank reports (tried different locations across the world). Even running `traceroute6 myapi.com` on the command line shows the same error: `No address associated with hostname`.

Comment: That means GoDaddy setting is incorrect

Comment: @TuanVA Okay, but what's wrong? Does it look like I'm missing something? If not, could it be a typo, maybe?

Comment: At GoDaddy, change Name to @ may help

Comment: @TuanVA I did some reading and found that we can't have a CNAME for the '@' domain. And I can't have an 'A' record here because Lambda doesn't have a fixed IP address. I think I'll let this domain rot and set up a new one from Route53 (transferring domains is too much hassle). Thanks for your time! :-)

Comment: Yeah. Good idea to change DNS to route53

Comment: @TuanVA No, not just DNS, I'm going for an entirely new domain purchased and managed from Route53. I'm really tired of this and don't have more hours to sink in. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206340/discussion-between-tuanva-and-ankush981).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a CNAME record at the apex or domain root with standard DNS services. I suggest you try using a hostname for your endpoint and using the CNAME there eg `api.example.com`.

Alternatively, you can move your DNS to Route 53. The Route 53 system does support aliases at the root domain level,  using the Alias record type.

For more information on Alias records in Route 53 see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html